# Is there such a query for mongodb?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I need to do a query on mongoDB due to I am developing in Java with Spring Boot and MongoDB. I know that this command is for arrays:

```
@Query("{ 'skills' : {$all : ?0}} ")
List<DataCV2> findAllSkillsInCV(ArrayList<String> skillsOfCV);
```

This query let me to find if all fields of the arraylist "skillsOfCV" are in the arraylist called "skills"
However, I am trying to pass an arraylist as "skillsOfCV" to compare all the fields with a string field in database.

```
@Query("{ 'experienceCV' : {$all : ?0}} ")
List<DataCV2> findAllExperienceInCV(ArrayList<String> experienceOfCV);
```

The field "experienceCV" is a string one, and I want to compare if this string field contains all the fields of the arraylist "experienceOfCV".How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to match `String` and `List<String>` using `$all` in a straightforward way.

The best bet is that use `String` field for the method and do the conversion programmatically.

Or else you can give a try with aggregation framework which has many useful aggregation operators.